# Deriving annoying ASP.NET class

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I would like to derive a new class from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl`, however I think when you derive a class you dont inherit it's constructors.

The difficulty this causes is that one of the constructors for this class has a parameter of type `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag`, which defines the html tag of the control/element created, and there is no way to set this after the class has been constructed/initialized.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to work through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need should add the same constructors to your own type. And then use :base(...) to call the base constructors.

```
public MyType(ParamClass a)
    :base(a)
{
}
```

You can also use non matching signatures between your type and the base type, as long as the signature of `:base(...)` matches the signature of the base type constructor. But you can only use expressions to define the value of the parameters passed to it. So you might want to use some static helper methods.

Answer (score 4):

This should help:
[A Crash Course on ASP.NET Control Development: Deriving New Controls from Existing Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479311.aspx)

just follow this crash course and you will see how simple it is.

Comment: You've gotten three upvotes, but I must be blind because I can't see the answer on that page (which is to add a colon to derive the constructor also).

Comment: you can create the parametrized constructor in your derived class then you call : base(parameter) right on the right of the constructor and this passes the parameter to the base ctor.

Comment: I think this article provide much more value than simple usage of base class constructor call

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
public class MyWebControl: WebControl
{
    public MyWebControl(HtmlTextWriterTag tag) : base(tag) 
    {

    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you derive a base class, the base class constructor will also be derived. You can pass the `HtmlTextWriter` type to the derived class ctr and in the derived class define the ctr as `DervCtr(HtmlTextWriter) : base(HtmlTextWriter)`